# Site restriction in google search Api

Tags: php, api

I use google search web api in PHP.
I need to apply a site restriction and obtain only the results from Wikipedia. 
Help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: Simply Use the Wikipedia API instead of Google API.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I don't know how to use Wikipedia API.

Comment: In other words how can I collect results referring to a query ??

Comment: Use `file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content')`

Comment: I added "site:https://fr.wikipedia.org" to the query and it works :) The problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Wiki API :

> file_get_contents('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revision‌​s&titles=New_York_Yankees&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content')